# What is the relationship between objscores and pcscores outcome values from princals {Gifi}?

Tags: categorical-data, pca

I am going to use the output of princals as the IVs in a regression with my DV.

What is the relationship between objscores and pcscores outcome values from  princals {Gifi}?

Which one of objscores and pcscores is better to be used in regression with DV?

Thank you for your kind help.
Yours,
Amir